# Like encodeAsBase64 methods does Grails provides encryption/decryption methods?

Tags: java, grails, encryption

Are there any easy way to encrypt/decrypt only a particular field, in my domain model in grails? Are there any Java classes that can be used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "encrypt/decrypt". Encryption in general is a rather _deep_ subject, and what is acceptable for a particular project depends 100% on the needs of that project. Personally, I would be rather wary of any drop-in encryption piece.

Comment: @cdeszaq: I want encryption the way that MySql's `AES_ENCRYPT` function do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to encrypt the data in the database, but have decrypted data in your Domain class you could use a custom UserType, which will handle the encrypt/decrypt for you.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#customHibernateTypes

http://www.redtoad.ca/ataylor/2011/12/encrypting-a-database-column-in-grails/